# Django form, display through field in a form

Tags: django, django-forms, many-to-many

I have 3 models, shown below. I want to display a form where i can create a navMenu with posts and then select the position of those posts, I can bring in the post to a form but I don't know how to add the through field post_postiton into the form, any help would be very much appreciated

[image]

Comment: Do you want to make a combined form which contains all three models ?

Comment: I thought that I only needed to use the NavMemu model because I add all the model connected to it. My goal is to create a form where I can create a Nav item with multiple post in it and each post has a position I can set.